# Will Ubuntu Phone OS be entirely open source?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

If so, how could mobile carriers like AT&T lock the phone to work only with their SIM?
Thanks!

Comment: I think these two questions should be separated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time of writing, there's no clear statement on *to what extent* it will be open source. It will be built *using* and *based on* a lot of open source components, yes, e.g. OpenGL, Linux kernel, QML, etc.

It may consists of some closed source parts for various reasons: firmware for hardware support, a way to improve security (not discussing if that would be a good idea here), etc.

> If [Ubuntu OS would be entirely open source], how could mobile carriers like AT&T lock the phone to work only with their SIM?

Open source software and a SIM-lock aren't really related here.

The radio part of a phone is a completely independent piece of hardware. The SIM-lock is usually in there, rather than a check in software. It can be controlled (locked/unlocked) however with hardware-specific calls to this. Android is no different in this, as the kernel-level here is also Linux (GPL).

Comment: Please update, if things change...

Comment: @Naveen Anyone can update/edit answers/questions here.

Answer (score 3):

According to this interview with project manager Richard Collins (around 5:10 in), it will be the exact same model as Ubuntu is on the desktop, with a proper upstream and the ability for people to participate and open source:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4lOpNajx3xI